# Program that uses while loops to calculate the first n Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, while-loop, putty, fibonacci

When I run it and input a number it just repeats it over non-stop.  for example if i put a 3 it will do this
3
3
3
3
3
BUT NON STOP

```
int main()
{
int current=0, prev=1, prev2=1, fibnum;
cout << "Enter the number of Fibonacci numbers to compute: ";
cin >> fibnum;
if (fibnum <=0)
{
    cout << "Error: Enter a positive number: ";
}
while (fibnum > 0){
    current = prev + prev2;
    prev = prev2;
    prev2 = current;
    current++;

    cout << "," << fibnum;
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I now have it as While 9=(fibnum != 0) { Looks like that helped but now I get a bunch of different numbers

Comment: Take a piece of paper, write down the variable names, and execute the code in your head, writing it down how the values of the variables change at each step. (Or step through code with a debugger.)

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you're using fibnum as a counter and you write it out as the current number in the fibonacci sequence. Also your loop will never stop since the value of fibnum never changes. You should also go over the way fibonacci works, it is the sum of the two numbers that became before it self.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems with the code:

1. You never assign anything to `fibnum` inside the body of the loop, so its value never changes.
2. The purpose of `current++` is entirely unclear.

Basically, you need to decide on the exact meaning of every variable, **and stick to it throughout**. The way these variables are being used, there's clearly confusion around the purpose of `current` and `fibnum`.

Comment: fibNum is assigned from stdin

Comment: @JesusRamos: Yes, it's read from stdin **before the loop**.  After the loop starts it never changes, so the loop never exits.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int current=0, prev=0, prev2=1, fibnum;
    cout << "Enter the number of Fibonacci numbers to compute: ";
    cin >> fibnum;
    if (fibnum <=0){
        cout << "Error: Enter a positive number: ";
    }
    while (fibnum--){
        cout << prev ;
        current = prev + prev2;
        prev = prev2;
        prev2 = current;
        if(fibnum)
            cout << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
int current_fib_num = 0;
....
while (current_fib_num++ != fibNum)
{
    ....
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: ok I did that but now it just gives me a bunch of different numbers non-stop.

Comment: add those lines of code, current++ doesn't make any sense the way you use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to fix.

You need to have a count variable;

```
int current=0, prev=0, prev2=1, fibnum;

int count;
```

....

To output the first number before the loop

```
cout<<prev2;
```

You can change this to a for loop to make it easier to count the numbers

```
for(count = 0; count <= fibnum; count++){
    current = prev + prev2;
    prev = prev2;
    prev2 = current;
```

You need to print current, not fibnum -> fibnum is the total numbers that you need to print

```
    cout << "," << current;
}
```

Comment: No, you don't need more variables.  There are already more than necessary, see my answer.  And incrementing `count` twice per loop is not going to give the desired result.

Comment: @BenVoigt The count++ in the loop was an oversight - was just converting the while to a for.
And yes, another variable is not necessary, but i feel that it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers note that you can use benefits of recursion if you need to calculate fib number with some certain number. Something like that:

```
#include <cstddef>

std::size_t fib( std::size_t num )
{
    // For first two numbers
    if (num <= 2)
        return 1;

    return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2);
}
```

but you must keep in mind that this will lead to redundant calculations 'coz of repeatable recalc of same numbers and stack use for transmitting function args.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print fibnum, but it is not changing inside the while loop.
You should be printing current instead.
Also you need to set a counter that will see the end of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
  int a=1, b=1, nums_to_print;
  while (1) {
    cout << "Enter the number of Fibonacci numbers to compute: ";
    cin >> nums_to_print;
    if (nums_to_print > 0) {
      while (1) {
        cout << a;
        b += a;
        a = b - a;
        if (--nums_to_print) cout << ",";
        else break;
      }
      cout << "\n";
      return 0;
    }

    cout << "Error: Enter a positive number.\n";
  }
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/3H8Fq

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
         int i=0,j=1;
        int c,n,count=0,d;
        cout<<"enter num";
        cin>>n;
        c=i+j;
        cout<<i<<j;
    while(count<n-2)
        {   d=j+c;
            cout<<d;
            j=c;
            c=d;
            count++;
        }
         return 0;
    }
```